# multiple plot for customized subset data in R

Tags: r, plot, subset

For the following data set, I can create plot for each ID. There are six ID, each repeated 4 times.

```
data=data.frame(ID=rep(1:6,each=4), y.value=c(1:24), x.value=seq(0,11.5, by=0.5))

setwd("C:/Users/mnudd/Desktop")
pdf(file = "myplot.pdf")
for( id.no in 1:6){
  plot(data$y.value[data$ID==id.no]~data$x.value[data$ID== id.no],xlim=c(0,12),ylim=c(0,25),type="l",col="black",
       xlab="time", ylab= "",main = paste("ID number", id.no), data=data)
  points(data$y.value[data$ID==id.no]~data$x.value[data$ID==id.no])
}
dev.off()
```

Now I would like to create the same plot for the following subset data1,

```
data1=data[data$ID  %in% c(1,3,4),]
setwd("C:/Users/mnudd/Desktop")
pdf(file = "myplot1.pdf")
for( id.no in 1:length(unique(data1$ID))){
  plot(data1$y.value[data1$ID==id.no]~data1$x.value[data1$ID== id.no],xlim=c(0,12),ylim=c(0,25),type="l",col="black",
       xlab="time", ylab= "",main = paste("ID number", id.no), data=data)
  points(data1$y.value[data1$ID==id.no]~data1$x.value[data1$ID==id.no])
}
dev.off()
```

From the above code, I am expecting three plot in the pdf file and each plot title should be corresponding to the id number that first plots title should be 
ID number 1, ID number 3, and ID number 4.

Unfortunately, the loop for the subset data is not working. Is there any general loop or function if the subset is large?
Appreciate your kind help.

Comment: *Is there any general loop or function if the subset is large?* Aren't you already applying a loop? What is the problem? You also mention *I am expecting three plot* ... are you not getting your expected results?

Comment: The loop for the subset data is not working? @Parfait

Comment: Change `1:length(unique(data1$ID))` to `unique(data1$ID)`

Comment: Yes, it's working. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `by` (object-oriented wrapper to `tapply`) which essentially is the apply family version to loop through a data set off of `unique` values in a column:

```
# FULL DATA
output <- by(data, data$ID, function(sub) {
  plot(sub$y.value ~ sub$x.value, xlim=c(0,12), ylim=c(0,25), type="l", col="black",
       xlab="time", ylab= "", main = paste("ID number", sub$ID[[1]]))
  points(sub$y.value ~ sub$x.value)
})

# SUBSET DATA
data1 <- data[data$ID  %in% c(1,3,4),]

output <- by(data1, data1$ID, function(sub) {
  plot(sub$y.value ~ sub$x.value, xlim=c(0,12), ylim=c(0,25), type="l", col="black",
       xlab="time", ylab= "", main = paste("ID number", sub$ID[[1]]))
  points(sub$y.value ~ sub$x.value)
})
```

With a function:

```
proc_plot <- function(sub) {
  plot(sub$y.value ~ sub$x.value, xlim=c(0,12), ylim=c(0,25), type="l", col="black",
           xlab="time", ylab= "", main = paste("ID number", sub$ID[[1]]))
  points(sub$y.value ~ sub$x.value)
}

# FULL DATA
output <- by(data, data$ID, proc_plot)

# SUBSET DATA
data1 <- data[data$ID  %in% c(1,3,4),]
output <- by(data1, data1$ID, proc_plot)
```